# How is possible put QGraphicsView to own method as argument?

Tags: c++, qt

So, I have the source code for a training. Where I want to do operation with QGraphicsView named *pp* in the own class *ProcessPicture*.
I would ask you, is it possible to put the QGraphicsView object to the method of own class? If yes, please tell me how or lead me on answer.
For a detailed description after releasing button will done the *on_processPic_pushButton_released()* where is called the method of *pp* object. This method take a *ui->graphicsview* as argument. This argument will used in the pp.drawrectangle(ui->graphicsview).

The code is without error or warning, only it is not draw the rectangle to the ui->graphicsview. When I take a source code from pp.drawrectangle() and try it, in the *on_processPic_pushButton_released()* all is fine. So I think that i miss some knowledge.

Lets look on my source code.

**processpicture.h**

```
#ifndef PROCESSPICTURE_H
#define PROCESSPICTURE_H

#include "QString"
#include "QPicture"
#include "QGraphicsView"

class ProcessPicture
{
public:
    ProcessPicture();
    void draw(QGraphicsView out);
    void draw_rectangle(QGraphicsView out);

private:    
    QString path = "***/Untitled.bmp";
    QImage img;
};

#endif // PROCESSPICTURE_H
```

**processpicture.cpp**

```
#include "processpicture.h"
#include "QGraphicsScene"
#include "QGraphicsPixmapItem"

ProcessPicture::ProcessPicture()
{
    img.load(path);
}

void ProcessPicture::draw_rectangle(QGraphicsView out){
    //QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QRect rect;
    rect.setRect(10,10,10,10);
    scene.addRect(rect);
    out.setScene(&scene);
    out.show();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "processpicture.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ProcessPicture *pp;
    //pp = new ProcessPicture;
    ~MainWindow();
private:

private slots:
    void on_processPic_pushButton_released();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    bool event(QEvent *event);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    pp = new ProcessPicture;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_processPic_pushButton_released()
{
    //pp->draw(ui->graphicsView);
    pp->draw_rectangle(ui->graphicsView);
}
```

For every non-toxic answer I thank.

Comment: Pass it by reference?  Also, I'm sure you could demonstrate your point with a lot less code than this, see [mre].

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question but... in `ProcessPicture::draw_rectangle` you declare `QGraphicsScene scene` as a local variable, so using `scene` with a graphics view won't do what you want -- `scene` will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope at the end of the function.